# Does DevDemon subscriptions work for non logged in users?

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

There's nothing to say it won't, but for non-logged in users, nothing is rendered between any of the {subs} tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are required to be a member to be a subscriber. The subscription is connect to their membership.  In an upcoming version we will add the member creation to the subscription tag.

Brad

Comment: Hi Brad, Do you know roughly when the new version that will support this is due for release?